# Running a perl script on windows without extension

Tags: perl, executable

I am trying to find a way to register the files with extension `.pl` as executables.
I spent some time on the web looking for a solution, but I couldn't find anything.

What I can do:
I made a script, let's call it *myscript.pl*
I can run it like this :

```
perl myscript.pl [my_script_parameters]
```

Now since the file is associated with perl, I can also run it as:

```
myscript.pl [my_script_parameters]
```

Now, I know that there is somewhere a list of extensions that are considered as **executables** (.exe, .bat, etc…). I would like to **add** `.pl` **to this list** so that I can run my script like this:

```
myscript [my_script_parameters]
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 13):

Yes, there is built-in support for this.  If you check the help for command FTYPE you will see a perl example.

C:>help ftype

> Displays or modifies file types used
>   in file extension associations
>
> FTYPE [fileType[=[openCommandString]]]
>
> fileType  Specifies the file type to
>   examine or change   openCommandString
>   Specifies the open command to use when
>   launching files
>                       of this type.
>
> Type FTYPE without parameters to
>   display the current file types that
>   have open command strings defined. 
>   FTYPE is invoked with just a file
>   type, it displays the current open
>   command string for that file type.
>   Specify nothing for the open command
>   string and the FTYPE command will
>   delete the open command string for the
>   file type.  Within an open command
>   string %0 or %1 are substituted with
>   the file name being launched through
>   the assocation.  %* gets all the
>   parameters and %2 gets the 1st
>   parameter, %3 the second, etc.  %~n
>   gets all the remaining parameters
>   starting with the nth parameter, where
>   n may be between 2 and 9, inclusive. 
>   For example:
>
> ```
> ASSOC .pl=PerlScript
> FTYPE PerlScript=perl.exe %1 %*
> ```
>
> would allow you to invoke a Perl
>   script as follows:
>
> ```
> script.pl 1 2 3
> ```
>
> If you want to eliminate the need to
>   type the extensions, then do the
>   following:
>
> ```
> set PATHEXT=.pl;%PATHEXT%
> ```
>
> and the script could be invoked as
>   follows:
>
> ```
> script 1 2 3
> ```

Comment: What version of Microsoft operating systems has this new feature?

Comment: It's been around since NT, maybe even earlier.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your reply. I tried but for some reason it didn't survive reboot. Probably I have to find the right config file which is called at boot time.

Comment: This will survive reboot if you permanently change PATHEXT as described.

Answer (score 6):

You can simply add ";.PL" to the PATHEXT environment variable. Right-click "My computer" > Properties > Advanced > Environment variables > System variables.

Comment: I have added `.pl` and `.PL` to `PATHEXT` but still my file opens with an editor. I am trying to execute as `C:\> newprog.pl`

Comment: Did you reboot? Or did you execute `set` to see if the PATHEXT variable has the new value in the console?

Answer (score -1):

Your best approach would be to write a batch file called `myscript.bat`, place it in your path, and have it run your script.. e.g.

```
@echo off
c:\perl\bin\perl.exe c:\scripts\myscript.pl %*
```

Comment: If you want to make a batch "wrapper" for a Perl script, use the `pl2bat` utility that comes with perl.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your reply. The problem if I use this method is that I have to make a batch for every script I write...