# How do I make my Perl scripts act like normal programs on Windows?

Tags: windows, perl

I want my Perl scripts to behave just like any other executable (*.exe file).

- When I double-click on `myscript.pl` I want it to execute instead of opening in a text editor.
- I want to run `myscript.pl` instead of `perl myscript.pl`.
- I really want to run `myscript` instead of `myscript.pl`.
- I want to run `program | myscript` instead of `program | perl myscript.pl`.
- I want to be able to run my script via drag & drop.

---

There are a number of changes you have to make on Windows to make all of 
these things work. Users typically stumble upon things that *don't* work one at 
a time; leaving them confused whether they've made an error, there's a bug in 
Perl, there's a bug in Windows, or the behavior they want just isn't possible. 
This question is intended to provide a single point of reference for making 
everything work up front; ideally before these problems even occur.

Related questions:

- [How do I make Perl scripts recognize parameters in the Win32 cmd console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695188/how-do-i-make-perl-scripts-recognize-parameters-in-the-win32-cmd-console)
- [Running a perl script on windows without extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677114/running-a-perl-script-on-windows-without-extension)
- [Perl execution from command line question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013341/perl-execution-from-command-line-question)
- [How can I read piped input in Perl on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480069/how-can-i-read-piped-input-in-perl-on-windows)
- [Perl on Windows, file associations and I/O redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286873/perl-on-windows-file-associations-and-i-o-redirection)
- [How do I create drag-and-drop Strawberry Perl programs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705851/how-do-i-create-drag-and-drop-strawberry-perl-programs)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

*Note: The actions below require administrative privileges. For
steps utilizing the command prompt it must be launched via "Run as
administrator" on Windows Vista / Windows 7.*

#### Associate *.pl files with perl

Run the following commands at a shell prompt:

```
assoc .pl=PerlScript
ftype PerlScript=C:\bin\perl.exe "%1" %*
```

Replace `C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe` with the path to your Perl installation. This
enables you to run `myscript.pl` instead of `perl myscript.pl`.

Default install locations are:

- ActivePerl: `C:\Perl`
- Strawberry Perl: `C:\Strawberry`

#### Add `.PL` to your PATHEXT environment variable.

This makes Windows consider *.pl files to be executable when searching your
PATH. It enables you to run `myscript` instead of `myscript.pl`.

You can set it for the current cmd session

```
set PATHEXT=%PATHEXT%;.PL
```

To set it permanently (under Windows Vista or Windows 7)

```
setx PATHEXT %PATHEXT%;.PL
```

Under Windows XP you have to use the GUI:

1. Right-click My Computer, and then click Properties.
2. Click the Advanced tab.
3. Click Environment variables.
4. Select PATHEXT, then click Edit.
5. Append `;.PL` to the current value.

#### Make I/O redirection work

I/O redirection (e.g. `program | myscript`) doesn't work for programs started
via a file association. There is a registry patch to correct the problem.

1. Start Registry Editor.
2. Locate and then click the following key in the registry:
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer`
3. On the Edit menu, click Add Value, and then add the following registry value:

   - Value name: `InheritConsoleHandles`
   - Data type: `REG_DWORD`
   - Radix: `Decimal`
   - Value data: `1`
4. Quit Registry Editor.

**Warning:** In principle, this should only be necessary on Windows XP. In my experience it's also necessary in Windows 7. In Windows 10 this is actively harmful—programs execute but produce nothing on stdout/stderr. The registry key needs to be set to 0 instead of 1.

See also:

- [STDIN/STDOUT Redirection May Not Work If Started from a File Association](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321788)
- [Perl Scripts on Windows 10 run from Explorer but not Command Prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38887076/perl-scripts-on-windows-10-run-from-explorer-but-not-command-prompt#38901036)

If patching the registry isn't an option running `program | perl -S myscript.pl`
is a less annoying work-around for scripts in your PATH.

#### Add a drop handler

Adding a drop handler for Perl allows you to run a Perl script via drag & drop;
e.g. dragging a file over the file icon in Windows Explorer and dropping it
there. Run the following script to add the necessary entries to the registry:

```
use Win32::TieRegistry;
$Registry->Delimiter("/");
$perlKey = $Registry-> {"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/Perl/"};
$perlKey-> {"shellex/"} = {
    "DropHandler/" =>  {
        "/" => "{86C86720-42A0-1069-A2E8-08002B30309D}"
}};
```

Comment: out of curiosity, why do you provide 4 different techniques for the above steps when all 4 can be achieved through registry manipulation?

Comment: Well, "there's more than one way to do it" after all :)

Comment: @ivancho: The primary reason is that this is a collection of data gathered from various places. A secondary reason is an aversion to using a sledgehammer (registry editing) when a finishing hammer will suffice. That said, I would find a comprehensive "run this *.reg file" answer useful, if not terribly enlightening.

Comment: @Michael. Great tips. My lack of being a Windows person bites me sometimes and the tip about redirection will make my life easier pretty well forever. Are there any side effects to it?

Comment: @Nic Gibson: It's a bug fix for Windows XP so it shouldn't have any side effects. The linked Microsoft kb article has the details.

Comment: *Thank you!* The InheritConsoleHandles fix was the crucial part I was missing. This enables putting Perl scripts in locations in the PATH and never having to wonder whether `perl -S` is needed. (Still it bugs me that that KB article says the "problem was fixed in XP SP 1" yet you *still* need to manually perform the registry change...  Implying that this will need to be done on every PC you work with!  I'll make myself a .REG file to do this, but grrrrr...)

Comment: For others who have tried this, did the last item, Drag and Drop, take effect right away after running that script? Or did you have to reboot your machine? I just tried it, and I see that key in my registry now but when I drag a text file onto my Perl script it does not highlight. If I directly click the Perl script though, it does run in a console so the Perl script itself is being properly recognized as executable.

Comment: `setx PATHEXT=%PATHEXT%;.PL` caused `ERROR: Invalid syntax.`. Replacing the `=` with a space ` ` worked. I would edit this answer, but I'm not a windows guru. Maybe someone else can verify that this is necessary and that I didn't make some other mistake and then we can edit the answer.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare: Good catch. Updated.

Comment: As of 5.24, Strawberry adds a Perl directory, i.e. c:\Strawberry\Perl\bin

Comment: For me, parameters to programs are not getting passed. If i print `$#ARGV` in a script, it says `-1` (no args passed). The `%*` is supposed to handle this, but doesn't seem to work for me. not sure if anything changed in win10?

Comment: Somehow on Windows10 I wasn't getting parameters to my scripts. I got it working by doing following additional steps (follow at your own risk!): delete registry keys: `HKCR/.pl`, `HKCR/pl_auto_file`, `HKCR/PerlScript`, `HKCU/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Explorer/FileExts/.pl`. Then open task manager and kill all explorer.exe tasks (your taskbar goes away--don't worry), then in task manager do File/Run New Task and enter explorer.exe, then repeat the command-line commands in answer, then kill/restart explorer.exe.

Comment: Concerning the drop handler: What means "drag a file over a file"? Drag a perl script over a data file, drag a data file over a perl script, drag a perl script over a perl script or something different?

Comment: @Ariser: The drop handler enables you to drag a data file (any file really, but typically data) and drop it onto a Perl script. It launches the script with file as an argument.

Comment: @Kip, I had a similar problem to yours. I had set 'assoc' and 'ftype', but also had set Notepad text editor via the GUI, and when I tried to execute a script, Windows invoked Notepad to edit the script instead of running my script. I finally found salvation [here](https://superuser.com/questions/361816/pass-command-line-arguments-to-windows-open-with), which advises deleting some reigstry keys that Windows used in preference to assoc and ftype.

Answer (score 7):

Convert your perl scripts into batch files using [pl2bat](http://p3rl.org/pl2bat) once they are ready to be run by users.

The trick works through the `perl -x` switch which, according to `perldoc perlrun`, makes Perl search for the first line looking like `#!.*perl`.

Answer (score 2):

After following the instructions in the accepted answer, a double click still led to .pl files opening with Notepad in Windows 10 — even when perl.exe was set as the default file handler.

After finding Jack Wu's comment at [ActivePerl. .pl files no longer execute but open in Notepad instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20601270/activeperl-pl-files-no-longer-execute-but-open-in-notepad-instead) I was able to run perl scripts on double-click as such:

- Select and right-click a .pl file
- Use the "Open With" submenu to "Choose another app"
- Select "Always use this app to open .pl files" (do this now – you won't get the chance after you have selected a program)
- Scroll to the bottom of the "Other options" to find "More apps", and select "Look for another app on this PC"
- Navigate to C:/path/to/perl/bin/ and select `Perl5.16.3.exe` (or the equivalent, depending on which version of Perl you have installed: but *not* `Perl.exe`)

Then the Perl icon appears next to .pl files and a double-click leads to them opening in Perl every time, as desired.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the assoc and ftype methods and they didn't work for me.

What worked was editing this registry key:

`Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Applications\perl.exe\shell\open\command`

It was set to:
`"C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe" "%1"`

When it should be:
`"C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe" "%1" %*`

It is the same content as the ftype, but for arcane windows reasons, I had to set it there too.

Answer (score 1):

Like some others, I had set 'assoc' and 'ftype', but also had set Notepad text editor via the GUI, and when I tried to execute a script via the command line, Windows invoked Notepad to edit the script instead of running my script.

Using the GUI to instead point the .pl file association to the script-running executable was not much of an improvement, since it would invoke the executable on my script, but would pass no command-line arguments (even when I invoked my script from the command line).

I finally found salvation [here](https://superuser.com/questions/361816/pass-command-line-arguments-to-windows-open-with) which advised me to delete some registry keys.

Key quote:
"The problem is that if you have already associated the program with the extension via the Open With dialog then you will have created an application association, instead of a file extension association, between the two. And application associations take precedence."

In my case, following the instructions to use RegEdit to delete

> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT \ Applications \ perl.exe

where perl.exe is the name of my Perl executable, and then also deleting:

> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT \ .pl

seemed to solve my problem, and then (after re-executing 'assoc' and 'ftype' commands as shown in other answers) I could then execute scripts from cmd.exe and have them run with access to their command-line parameters.

Some other related information [here](https://superuser.com/questions/53948/how-do-i-restore-bat-files-association-with-the-system-make-them-run-when-doub).