# File Type .pl Association and Using cmd.exe to Run the Script

Tags: windows, perl, cmd

I've made a new file type .pl (Explorer->Tools->Folder Options...->File Types). Now I wanted to make a new Action which will call cmd.exe and automatically run PERL script.I don't know what to write under "Applications used to perform action" ,I have to pass cmd.exe certain arguments but I don't know which.
Form of arguments should ,I suppose, be:[cmd.exe] <*file location*> **perl** <*file name*>

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make my Perl scripts act like normal programs on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727480/how-do-i-make-my-perl-scripts-act-like-normal-programs-on-windows)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To permanently associate `*.pl` with `perl.exe`, at a command prompt type the following.

```
assoc .pl=PerlScript
ftype PerlScript=c:\perl\bin\perl.exe %1 %*
```

Note that you could also associate `*.pl` with `wperl.exe`, which will run the script without a visible command window. `wperl.exe` is part of the [ActiveState perl distribution](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl).

Comment: That would be a per-user association I guess?

Comment: Great it works!But is there any way to PAUSE window after program is finished?

Answer (score 0):

Application used to perform actions:

"c:\perl\bin\perl.exe" "%1" %*

assuming "c:\perl\bin\perl.exe" is the correct file spec of your Perl executable.