# Sphinx training acoustic model on opens slave_feat.pl in text editor

Tags: windows, cmusphinx

When i run the training, it opens the slave_feat.pl file and when I run it, this error appears. any idea about solving it ?  [Configuration not defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zu4Dk.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ActivePerl. .pl files no longer execute but open in Notepad instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20601270/activeperl-pl-files-no-longer-execute-but-open-in-notepad-instead)

Comment: You need to configure perl to execute the script instead of opening it in IDE.