# .pl files open in notepad

Tags: windows, perl, file-association

I am new to xampp, and also, I am new to Perl programming.
I just tried to open the file C:\xampp\cgi-bin\printenv.pl and I made a mistake.

I chose the default program to open that file extension as Notepad, with the option `always use the selected program to open this kind of file`.

Now when I try to run .pl files from cmd it opens them in Notepad instead of executing. Please reply. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using pl2bat or some modern variation of it (I haven't used windows for ages, so I don't really know). The point is turning a .pl into a .bat file which generally looks like `@C:\path\to\perl <this_script>\nexit\n#!/usr/bin/perl -x`. -x means "ignore anything before the `#!perl` line.

Comment: [How do I make my Perl scripts act like normal programs on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727480/how-do-i-make-my-perl-scripts-act-like-normal-programs-on-windows)

Answer (score 9):

Type the following at a shell prompt:

```
assoc .pl=PerlScript
ftype PerlScript="c:\...\bin\perl.exe" "%1" %*
```

(Replace `...` with the correct path.)

Answer (score 2):

ikegami's suggestion did not work for me in Windows 10, but after finding Jack Wu's comment at [ActivePerl. .pl files no longer execute but open in Notepad instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20601270/activeperl-pl-files-no-longer-execute-but-open-in-notepad-instead) I was able to solve the problem as such:

- Select and right-click a .pl file
- Use the "Open With" submenu to "Choose another app"
- Select "Always use this app to open .pl files" (do this now – you won't get the chance after you have selected a program)
- Scroll to the bottom of the "Other options" to find "More apps", and select "Look for another app on this PC"
- Navigate to C:/path/to/perl/bin/ and select `Perl5.16.3.exe` (or the equivalent, depending on which version of Perl you have installed: but *not* `Perl.exe`)

Then the Perl icon appears next to .pl files and a double-click leads to them opening in Perl every time, as desired.