# How do I make an executable to avoid command prompt on Windows?

Tags: perl, executable, command-prompt

The reason I'm asking this is because after half an hour of failing to figure out what key word or jargon to use I figured it wouldn't hurt to ask here.

What I'm currently doing is getting a perl code to run using the good ol:

```
perl myPerlScript.pl
```

To get it to run. What I'd like to do for simplicity of presentation as a prototype would be to figure out how to make a script that I can run as an executable that would effectively be just a replacement of that. I know on Linux/Unix you can make bash scripts, but I'm trying to run this like I would Steam or other executables. Any advice or am I asking for something impossible? Having the command prompt pop up in the background is an option but preferably avoidable.

Also I've been using Cava Packager, but it's so bulky I figured since I'm only using one script there would be an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727480/how-do-i-make-my-perl-scripts-act-like-normal-programs-on-windows/4727490#4727490) shows how to make it so you can simply do

```
myPerlScript.pl
```

or even simply

```
myPerlScript
```

(Another way of achieving the latter is with the `pl2bat` tool.)

Comment: Thanks! I'm sorry it was a simple answer, but when you don't know what combination of words to use in search engines things can get a bit hard to find.

Comment: Okay so after trying that I found out that didn't quite solve my issue. Perhaps it's because I'm on Windows 8, but the solution instead of working continues to try and open Notepad++ instead of running the program.

Comment: What does `assoc .pl` output? And what does `ftype XXX` output (where `XXX` is what's on the right of `=` in `assoc .pl`'s output)?

Comment: assoc's output is PerlScript like in the example, ftype's output is C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe. But it turns out that I can get it to work through double-clicking (took some registry modifications) and personally that's all I really need, but your effort is appreciated!

Comment: Wow, can't explain that. (I presume it's actually `C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe "%1" %*`)

Comment: Yeah sorry, it's actually that but yeah it refuses to work, I at first assumed it was the registry being what it is, but once I was there I just tweaked it so double-clicking would do the job.