# Perl script on Widows10 can't get command line parameters

Tags: perl, windows-10

Perl script on Windows 10 can't get command line parameters if command line does not begin with "perl". The same works correctly on Windows7. Please look at example:

```
D:\>ver

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.503]

D:\>assoc .pl
.pl=PerlScript

D:\>ftype PerlScript
PerlScript=D:\x\perl\perl\bin\perl.exe "%1" %*

D:\>type tst.pl
# tst.pl

use strict ;
use warnings ;

print '$0 = '. $0 ."\n" ;
unless( $ARGV[ 0 ] ) { die "No args.\n\n" }
my $i = 0 ;
for my $arg ( @ARGV ) { print $i++ .': '. $arg ."\n" }

D:\>perl tst.pl
$0 = tst.pl
No args.


D:\>perl tst.pl FIRST SECOND
$0 = tst.pl
0: FIRST
1: SECOND

D:\>tst.pl FIRST SECOND
$0 = D:\tst.pl
No args.
```

Comment: See also [How do I make my Perl scripts act like normal programs on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4727480/2173773)

Comment: Yes, I saw the link above. I think this is specific Windows 10 problem. It is ok on Windows7.
I tried a new Perl installation from http://strawberryperl.com/download/5.30.0.1/strawberry-perl-5.30.0.1-32bit.msi at other PC with Win.10. Test script works OK.

Comment: So Perl-installation from MSI file is proven OK, but installation from ZIP file with manual settings (assoc, ftype) in the same way, as on Windows7, has any problem (specifics registry settings?).

Comment: After Perl-installation from MSI file is one PC OK (with 32-bit Windows 10), but second PC is not OK (with 64-bit Windows 10). The same behavior as above. It should be any local problem (?).